# How to prevent joining tables in eager relationships when using criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have three classes say `A`, `B` and `C` as below:

Class `A` has a `OneToOne` relation with `B`:

```
Class A {
   @OneToOne
   B b;
}
```

And `B` has an eager relation with `C`.

```
Class B {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=fetchType.EAGER)
    C c;
}
```

I want to have a criteria (on `A`) and join it with `B` to retrieve some data from these two tables. But when I use `createAlias` (or any other specific joins) table `C` is joined as well. (Apparently because of the eager relation between `B` and `C`). Something like this:

```
Criteria aCrit = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
aCrit.createAlias("a.b", "b");
aCrit.setProjection(Projections.property("b.name");
aCrit.list();
```

The question is, as I have no need of `C`, I do not want it to be joined. How can I manually prevent such action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to specify the fetch mode dynamically just for your query:

```
Criteria aCrit = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
aCrit.createAlias("a.b", "b");
aCrit.setFetchMode("b.c", FetchMode.SELECT)
aCrit.setProjection(Projections.property("b.name");
aCrit.list();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and let you know the outcome. I wonder why not using `FetchMode.LAZY` itself?

Comment: The enum constant `FetchMode.LAZY` is deprecated: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/FetchMode.html